# Why do we access the value of the bytes pointed at by the char* instead of the value of the pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers

From previous questions in the topic, I've understood that the pointer points to the first character of a string, and expects the following characters to take part of the string until a null character.
My question is how does this declaration *for example* work:

```
 const char* name = "abc";
```

As far as I understand, the value of the const char* isn't the phrase "abc", it's an integer which points to the location of the "a" character in my memory. **This part is which I don't understand. Why?**

Shouldn't we only be able to give value to a byte by dereferencing the pointer first?

Comment: I think the question could be focused better to the point puzzling you if you used int as example data type. It seems to me that the intricacies of C-like "string" initialisation in C++ is making things complicated here. By the way, the code you show seems to indicate that you are thinking in C, not C++. Consider tagging accordingly. Sorry if I guess too much into your phrasing, only trying to help.

Comment: Pointers are not integers, even if the memory-model of your implementation models addresses that way, known as a flat address space and quite common for user-programs today. Pointers are pointers.

Comment: Consider making the question a little clear by adding code (or pseudo-code) that show what you want to do.  Perhaps there is a compiler error we can help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const char* name = "abc";
```

is basically short for:

```
// compiler makes up a random name
static const char _abc_string_235o8v3tiue[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};
const char* name = _abc_string_235o8v3tiue;
```

which is short for:

```
// compiler makes up a random name
static const char _abc_string_235o8v3tiue[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};
const char* name = &_abc_string_235o8v3tiue[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why? because thats what pointers do, their value is a memory adress. The type of `"abc"` is actually `const char[4]` (one for the null terminator). And arrays can decay to pointers to their first element.

> Shouldn't we only be able to give value to a byte by dereferencing the pointer first?

No. To assign a value to an object you assign the value to the object. When you want to assign soemthing to what a pointer points to then you dereference the pointer:

```
int x;
int* y = &x;  // <- initialize the pointer with address of x
*y = 5;       // dereference y and assign 5 to x
```

For how the memory for the string literal is managed I refer you to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2740728/4117728

Comment: In your example if we were to add ```std::cout << y;```  the output would be a hexadecimal number. If we were to do the same thing with the *name* variable given in my ecample, it outputs "abc" instead of the hexadecimal number pointing to "a". this is where my understanding stops.

Comment: @Chef what do you mean? The value of `y` does not change in the last line

Comment: @Chef for all types (optionally const) T **except** `char`, the function `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, T*)`, prints the pointer value. `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const char*)` assumes it's a nul-terminated string and prints that. It's a quirk, because of the historical use of nul-terminated char arrays as text